# INSERT INTO SELECT query that includes the GETDATE() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an `INSERT INTO SELECT statement` (below) that works fine but I can't figure out how to also populate a datetime field in tbl named rundate.

In other words, I want: `INSERT INTO tbl (title,invnum,rundate)` where rundate will get the value returned by the `GETDATE()` function.

```
INSERT INTO tbl (title,invnum) 
SELECT @title,t1.invnum FROM #InvenNums t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT title,invnum FROM tbl t2 
WHERE t2.invnum=t1.invnum AND t2.title=@title)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
INSERT INTO tbl (title, invnum, rundate)
    SELECT @title, t1.invnum, GETDATE()
    FROM #InvenNums t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl t2 WHERE t2.invnum = t1.invnum AND t2.title = @title);
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, thanks very much; works perfectly; thank you!